# Disabling automatic phone detection on Ipad in a web app

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have found that while using the 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
tag in iOS 4.3.5 the
<meta name="format-detection" content="telphone=no" />
tag does not work.  It will work in Safari, but not if the app is
launched from the home screen.

Has anyone found a working solution to this that doesn't involve adding tags to the number?
(I am dynamically getting the number from a database and using it to update so this is not an option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution.  In my case I was using span tags with the data inside them, and these were not allowing the disable-phone detection to work.  However, if I then wrapped the span tag in a anchor tag with text-decoration set to none, it would work.  Not sure why this is the case whith iOS 4.3.5 but hopefully this helps someone else as well.